# Add Hyperlink to Google Sheet using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently creating a Pre-Order Inventory Form in Google Sheets using Apps Script. Can I ask for help how can I add an hyperlink once I added an order in my Pre-Order Inventory form
[image: see pic for the inventory form] and the hyperlink to be visible in my database like this [image: see pic of what I wanted to make it like].

Here's the code:

```
sh = SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
shForm = sh.getSheetByName("FORM");
shDb = sh.getSheetByName("DATABASE");

function addNewItem() {
lRow = shDb.getLastRow();
rng = shForm.getRange("D8:D16");
rng_val = rng.getValues()

Logger.log(rng_val)

shDb.appendRow([lRow,rng_val[0][0],rng_val[1][0],rng_val[2][0],rng_val[3][0],rng_val[4][0],rng_val[5][0],rng_val[6][0],rng_val[7][0],rng_val[8][0]]);

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assume your sheet is called `FORM` and you want to fil in cell A2, you can use the following codes to add hyperlink:

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("FORM!A2");
var richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
   .setText("Porsche 911 GT3 RS Zamac")
   .setLinkUrl("https://example.com")
   .build();
range.setRichTextValue(richValue);
```

and if you want to use it with `appendRow()`, you can use [`_appendRows()` utility function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/8466) instead:

```
appendRows_(shDb, [varX, varY, varZ, richValue]);
```

Alternatively, you can make use of `HYPERLINK()` function. Just pass the formula to the cell:

```
shDb.appendRow([lRow, "=HYPERLINK(\"https://example.com\", \"Porsche 911 GT3 RS Zamac\")"]);
```

As Google Apps Script is based on JS, you should always escape the double quotes in the formula with backslashes.